# Java Regex to check "=number", ex "=5455"?

Tags: java, regex

I want to check a string that matches the format "=number", ex "=5455".

As long as the fist char is "=" & the subsequence is any number in [0-9] (dot is not allowed), then it will popup "correct" message.

```
    if(str.matches("^[=][0-9]+")){
        Window.alert("correct");
        }
```

So, is this `^[=][0-9]+` the correct one?

if it is not correct, can u provide a correct solution?

if it is correct, then can u find a better solution?

Comment: ...did you actually try it?

Comment: http://regexpal.com/ can help you

Comment: You don't need to give the anchor. While using `matches`, anchors are assumed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no big regex expert and more knowledgeable people than me might correct this answer, but:

- I don't think there's a point in using `[=]` rather than simply `=` - the `[...]` block is used to declare multiple choices, why declare a multiple choice of one character?
- I don't think you need to use `^` (if your input string contains any character before `=`, it won't match anyway). I'm unsure as to whether its presence makes your regex faster, slower or has no effect.

In conclusion, I'd use `=[0-9]+`

Answer (score 0):

That should be correct it is looking for an anchored at the beginning = sign and then 1 or more digits between 0-9

Comment: actually, it fails because that regex will return a match even for "=5455xxx"

Comment: @STTLCU. It won't. Anchors are assumed while using `matches()`. So, that regex is really - `^=[0-9]+$`, when written explicitly, but `^` and `$` are not needed.

Comment: @STTLCU given that the OP uses `matches()`, intentionally or not, it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will work, even though it can be simplified:

- `.matches()` does not really do regex matching, since it tries and matches *all* the input against the regex; therefore the beginning of input anchor is not needed;
- you don't need the character class around the `=`.

Therefore:

```
if (str.matches("=[0-9]+")) { ... }
```

If you want to match a string which only *begins* with that regex, you have to use a `Pattern`, a `Matcher` and `.find()`:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^=[0-9]+");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

if (m.find()) { ... }
```

And finally, `Matcher` also has `.lookingAt()` which anchors the regex only at the beginning of the input.